# Generate RTF Text from Chinese string stored in UTF8 database field

Tags: delphi, utf-8, rtf, cjk

In Delphi 7 (for a lot of reasons I can't convert the application in Xe) I must generate the RTF string from a Chinese string that is stored into a UTF8 field (in Firebird 2.5 table).

For example I read the field value that contain the UTF8 value of the string "史蒂芬·克拉申"  string  into a wiredstring and then I should convert to a string like this 
'ca\'b7\'b5\'d9\'b7\'d2\f1\'b7\f0\'bf\'cb\'c0\'ad\'c9\'ea\

The value of UTF8 field for the previous Chinese string is 'å²è’‚èŠ¬Â·å…‹æ‹‰ç”³'

How can I do that ?

I have done a lot of search but I haven't find  solutions.

Please give me some advice to solve this problem.

Thanks Massimo

Comment: https://www.zopatista.com/python/2012/06/06/rtf-and-unicode/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - thank you but anyway I'm not able to translate python code to delphi;

Comment: It's not about the code, but about how to encode Unicode in RTF. And you are doing it wrong. You should be encoding UTF16 values.

Comment: Sorry but I don't do anything; I just wanted to know how to translate the contents of a UTF8 string field into an RTF string using delphi 7. Thanks

Comment: What you need to do is use the UTF-16 RTF encoding as described in that article. You'll notice that it differs from the RTF encoding that you have in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I can't convert UTF8 to UTF16; I did many tests without being able to find a solution.
Could you indicate a function in Delphi 7 to carry out the conversion?
Also after having done it, do you know if there is an application to be able to generate an RTF file with this format ( \uN? control sequence; backslash ‘u’ followed by a signed 16-bit integer value in decimal and a placeholder character (represented here by a question mark)? I doubt that Delphi 7 cannot be used. Thank you.

Comment: `MultiByteToWideChar` does that conversion. You then have to be careful to ensure that you convert each 16 bit `WideChar` to a signed decimal integer. `IntToStr(Smallint(C))` where `C` is a `WideChar`.

Answer (score 1):

After several days I finally found a solution inspired by this post 
[Getting char value in Delphi 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347587/getting-char-value-in-delphi-7) and the conversion to decimal available on this site https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter

After loading the UTF8 value from the field I use UTF8Decode and then I convert to Rtf ..

```
var
  fUnicode : widestring;

  function UnicodeToRtf(const S: WideString): string;
   var
     I: Integer;
   begin
     Result := '';
     for I := 1 to Length(S) do
         Result := Result + '\u' + IntToStr(Word(S[I]))+'?';
   end;

begin
   fUnicode := Utf8Decode(DbChineseField.AsString);
   fRtfString := UnicodetoRtf(fUnicode);
   ..... 
end;
```